# Real time notifications for chatting applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, pusher

I am creating chatting web app. I implemented realtime functionality and typing indicator using pusher, but m unable to apply real time notification functionality.
please tell me how I can do that.
and is there any way to  use bootstrap tickers for notifications ?

Comment: could you please post some code to understand better where you are stuck?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to provide a [mcve] of the code you're struggling with, because at the moment this question is simply too broad. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular

Comment: @VikasSonichya i'm unable to code this time about notification. question is this that how can I add new message notification functionality in my project

Comment: and previously /i implemented typing indicator and real time functionality using pusher

Answer (score 0):

If you creating just simple web app, I advise to you to read about [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/real-time) in ASP.NET. It is easy to use, and simple to control.

Also you can check out this url:[The Simplest Thing Possible: Creating Push Notifications with SignalR](https://www.codemag.com/Article/1210071/The-Simplest-Thing-Possible-Creating-Push-Notifications-with-SignalR)

---

By the way, here the best example to create chat application using Pusher: [Web PUSH Notifications быстро и просто](https://habr.com/ru/post/321924/) ...but in Russian language))

Comment: i want to implement it using pusher

Comment: @MaryamMehmood, you can check that last link in habr.com. There are written all the scripts needed